# Account activation in Django

Tags: python, django

I want make account activation by email, i.e. send letter with link to complete registration to user. I see this technique in django password reset views. How this is worked? Where django save generated uid? In rails I see tutorial where password reset and account activation uids were saved in two fields in User model. This is true for password reset in django?  And what is best way to add account activation by email to my project? Must I extend User model or something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try [django-allauth](http://django-allauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/providers.html) it should cover your needs.

Comment: Thank you. But do you know about django password reset behavior? It save generated uids in field in User model or where?